Manga where the main character saves a village, gets killed by a church, and reincarnates into a human boy
So basically the main character just appears (not even he knows what or who he is) and goes to a village, but they catch him messing with his blood and call him a vampire and this is where he gets the name 'Nosferatu.'
Then he finds a village that has an abandoned castle and asks if he could live there and they say 'yes,' so he lives there studying his own body that is filled to the brim with magic. His blood is called mystil blood is really full of it. The main character also becomes the guardian of the village, as he seems to not age and he even teaches the children language and writing in his off-time.
But one day a plague appears and his village gets it from a merchant or something and he saves his village with own blood, but the church at the time doesn't like that and decides to blame the plague on the main character. The village chief, someone the main character knew since he was a child, has to kill the main character or the village will be deemed evil. The main character dies and is reincarnated as an illegitimate child of a noble.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Henkyou Gurashi no Maou, Tensei shite Saikyou no Majutsushi ni naru aka The Demon King of the Frontier Life, Reincarnated to Become the Strongest Mage by Sakaki Sengetsu and Muraichi


There was a mage called "The Lone Demon King" at the frontier. He was just a creature that never grew old, but he was loved by the villagers as something of a guardian deity. However, he was destroyed by a magic organization that sees his existence as dangerous. 200 years later, he is reincarnated as the second son of an aristocrat and obtains the strongest magic power.
"Let's pretend to be a human this time..."
However, being a human lover, he didn't particularly think of revenge and has decided to pretend to be human in this life. In his past life, he was the guardian deity of a region, and in this life, he's a local aristocrat, but he does not know common sense. He doesn't know how to take it easy. As the second son of an aristocrat, he is loved by his family and friends, and while he is regarded as a master of magic in the magic guild, he becomes an "Immortal Mage" behind the scenes.



Found with search terms of manga "nosferatu" "reincarnated" blood
